# Acer Aspire z5610 NVIDIA driver issue in 19.04

Tags: nvidia, acer, aspire

I would really appreciate your help in trying to configure my Nvidia-340 driver on an [Acer Aspire z5610](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual/User%20Manual_Acer_1.0_A_A.zip?acerid=634559662952792303&Step1=ALL-IN-ONE&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20Z5610&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6). I am a noob with Linux but have picked up quite a lot over the last few days. Right now I feel like a dyslexic neo throwing 1's and 0's at the screen tho. My brain is fried.

After a clean install everything looked good except that the resolution was 640 px and i could not change it in the display settings. I followed advice about installing the NVIDIA drivers and after a reboot my screen flashed white, black, then bands of primary colours.

I rebooted into a root shell, and did a combination of purging, updating etc (i cant remember the order) and I got back to screen displayed with 640px.

I can see in the Alternative drivers GUI that i have drivers, the NVIDIA-340 and the X.org Nouveau, but selecting either one makes no difference.

Also if i go to System/Nvidia X Server settings, again using the GUI interface then nothing is displayed in the popup window which should list the nvidia settings.

I don't know if this is an issue, but I had to set ACPI=off to install as I have an old BIOS, as i have noticed some people say the driver issue is related to UEFI, however I have no such settings in my BIOS.

What I find strange is that when I tested Ubuntu Disco from the USB (with ACPI=off, otherwise it would not work) the screen displayed properly.

I am sorry for the rather jumbled explanation as to the changes I have made, and the order I have done them in. I am sure that you can remember what it was like as a noob finding searching for one issue leads to or creates 20 more!!!

I have taken pics on my phone of various errors along the way, such as

'The repository does not have a release file' (after apt-get update)

*-display UNCLAIMED (top line after sudo lshw -c display)

ERROR: missing module or file name (after I made a cup of tea!!!)

The instructions I have followed along the way seem to have worked for other people in forums like this.

I am happy to generate error reports and upload them if that could help. I am determined not to go back to Windows, which currently takes several moons to boot up.

Any and all help is appreciated.
Kind Regards in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)